# Complementary pairs of Guanine and Cytosine

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I am new to TikZ and need help with drawing the following diagram of complementary pairs of Guanine and Cytosine.

[image: Complementary base pair of Guanine and Cytosine]

I am trying to do it the following way but do not know how to rotate and join the links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Chemistry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}]
\chemfig{*6((-H_2N)=N-*5(-\chembelow{N}{H}-=N-)=-(=O)-HN-[,,2])}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried any code? Have you a MWE?

Comment: Please give the O.P. some time to improve his post before voting to close or flagging it as LQ ...

Answer (score 8):

Package [`chemfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) provides a powerful interface for chemistry via TikZ (two LaTeX runs required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setatomsep{2em}
    \path
      node[anchor=base east] (Guanine)
      {\chemfig{%
        [:180]N(-[:0]@{L2}H)*6(-(=@{L1}O)-(*5(-N=-N(-R)-))=-N=%
        (-N(-[:0]@{L3}H)-[:240]H)-)}}
      (Guanine.base east)
      node[anchor=base west, xshift=-.15em] (Cytosin)
      {\chemfig{%
        [:-30]@{R2}N*6(-(=@{R3}O)-N(-R)-=-(-N(-[:180]@{R1}H)-[:60]H)=)}}
    ;
    \chemmove{%
      \foreach \i in {1, 2, 3} {
        \draw[-, dashed, shorten <=.2em, shorten >=.2em] (L\i) -- (R\i);
      }%
    }
    \path (Guanine.south west) (Cytosin.north east); % update bouning box
    \path[inner sep=0pt, below=1.5ex]
      (Guanine.south) node {Guanine}
      (Cytosin.south |- Guanine.south) node {Cytosine}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

As already noted `chemfig` is quite powerful. So powerful, that actually no additional TikZ is needed if the hydrogen bridges were drawn as bonds (from `chemfig`'s point of view, using the bond's fourth optional argument to make them dashed) and both molecules were drawn as one `chemfig` formula.

But even if you draw them both separately you can exploit the fact that you can give names to the nodes where the atoms are placed in in a `chemfig` formula (`@{<name>}`-syntax). To these nodes can later be referred to in another tikzpicture with `remember picture` and `overlay` options for which `chemfig` has the wrapper `\chemmove`. The only thing one has to take care of is that both molecules have the same baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname
  {\chemfig{@{H1}H-[:180](-[:-120]H)-[:120]*6(-N(-@{H2}H)-(=@{O3}O)-(*5(-N=-N(-R)-))=-N-)}}
  {Guanine}
\qquad
\chemname
  {\chemfig{@{O1}O=[:60]*6(-N(-R)-=-(-N(-[::60]@{H3}H)-[::-60]H)=@{N2}N-)}}
  {Cytosine}
\chemmove[dashed]{\draw (H1) -- (O1) (H2) -- (N2) (O3) -- (H3) ;}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even have the molecules as submols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\definesubmol{guanine}{
  @{hb-gua1}H-[:180](-[:-120]H)
  -[:120]*6(
    -N(-@{hb-gua2}H)
    -(=@{hb-gua3}O)
    -(*5(-N=-N(-R)-))
    =-N-
  )
}

\definesubmol{cytosine}{
  @{hb-cyt1}O=[:60]*6(
    -N(-R)
    -=-(
      -N(-[::60]@{hb-cyt3}H)
      -[::-60]H
    )
    =@{hb-cyt2}N-
  )
}

\begin{document}

\chemname{\chemfig{!{guanine}}}{Guanine}
\qquad
\chemname{\chemfig{!{cytosine}}}{Cytosine}
\chemmove[dashed]{\foreach \i in {1,2,3} { \draw (hb-gua\i) -- (hb-cyt\i) ;}}

\end{document}
```

(The picture is the same)